# As an API developer, when should I expect base class implementation to be called?

Tags: oop

I am currently developing an API that uses abstract classes with default implementations. While I have done this in the past I have not really thought of the philosophical implications of calls back to base.SomeMethod() in the derived class since the APIs were not intended for public consumption. Since this API is intended to be publicly visible, I am wondering how I should handle calls back into the base class. Is it OK for me to assume that the base call will always happen first or last in the derived implementation and I simply document the assumption for the implementer? Or should the base class calls have no side effects, so it wouldn't matter when the implementer calls the base class? Is there a rule of thumb for this?

Thanks.

Comment: I am curious why this is down voted. It seems like a reasonable question, I would like to be educated as to why it isn't.

Comment: Is base.SomeMethod being called by the derived class, or by some consumer? If it's the derived classes, the SomeMethod shouldn't be public.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it depends pretty much on the needs of your particular class. If you want to make sure that the base behavior is called (and maybe even in a special order) you can use a [template method](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html). I find this pattern as a really elegant way of providing subclasses extension points in a controlled way and I think is better than leaving a comment to the developer.

The obvious downside is that if you choose badly the hooks, you could be constraining too much the other developer. I remember once or twice having to override a template method because the hooks didn't allow me to perform the behavior I needed.

HTH